# PHP E-mail Feedback Form

Tags: php, html, forms, submission, feedback

```
<?php
$field_name = $_POST['cf_name'];
$field_email = $_POST['cf_email'];
$field_message = $_POST['cf_message'];

$mail_to = 'someemail@eample.com';
$subject = 'Feedback from '. $field_name

$body_message = 'From: '.$field_name."\n";
$body_message .= 'E-mail: '.$field_email."\n";
$body_message .= 'Message: '.$field_message;

$headers = 'From: '.$field_email."\r\n";
$headers .= 'Reply-To: '.$field_email."\r\n";

$mail_status = mail($mail_to, $subject, $body_message, $headers);

if ($mail_status) { ?>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        alert('Thank you for your feedback, have a nice day!');
        window.location = 'some undefined location';
    </script>
<?php
}
else { ?>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        alert('Sorry your feedback was not sent, please try again soon!');
        window.location = 'some undefined location';
    </script>
<?php
}
```

?>

I'm trying to create a form that submits the feedback to my desired email adress, the form seems to be running smoothly when i enter all the details but I am not receiving any emails?

Can anyone see why?

Thanks!

Comment: check the mail function error logs for any errors while sending emails.

Comment: Do you get a Javascript response? Is there anything in your error logs? Did you just forget the ; behind subject or is that also in your code?

Comment: Are you executing the script on your localhost? If so, have you set up a mail server?

Comment: I get a javascript response yes, which says thank you for your feedback. I'm executing onto another server

Comment: @James, check your mail in Trash or junk folder. If still not getting. add MIMI-Version in your header.

Comment: nothing coming through in trash or junk.

Comment: MIMI-Version added and still nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

write headers  like this :

```
$headers = "From: " . $field_email. "\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: ". $field_email. "\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";

example :

$from = "xyz@zz.com";
$to = "youremail@address.com";
$subject = "subject trail mail";
$mail_msg = "trail mail body";

$headers = "From: "  . $from . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: ". $from . "\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
$retval = mail ($to,$subject,$mail_msg,$headers);

if( $retval == true )  
{
    $st = "mail sent successfully";
}
else{
    $st = "mail error" ;
}
echo "mail Status : " . $st ;
```

Comment: Added these headers and still no emails through inbox, junk or trash

Answer (score 0):

`$subject = 'Feedback from '. $field_name`

should be:
`$subject = 'Feedback from '. $field_name;`

Comment: Good spot there, but i'm still not receiving any emails from the form.

Answer (score 0):

Is there actually anything being POST'ed? If I replace the three first POST with just data I get the mails correctly. Can you echo the value you're posting?

This code:

```
>  <?php $field_name = 'Name'; $field_email = 'name@mail.com';
> $field_message = 'This is the message';
> 
> $mail_to = 'freekgille@gmail.com'; $subject = 'Feedback from '.
> $field_name;
> 
> $body_message = 'From: '.$field_name."\n"; $body_message .= 'E-mail:
> '.$field_email."\n"; $body_message .= 'Message: '.$field_message;
> 
> $headers = 'From: '.$field_email."\r\n"; $headers .= 'Reply-To:
> '.$field_email."\r\n";
> 
> $mail_status = mail($mail_to, $subject, $body_message, $headers);
> 
> if ($mail_status) { ?>
>     <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
>         alert('Thank you for your feedback, have a nice day!');
>     </script> <?php } else { ?>
>     <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
>         alert('Sorry your feedback was not sent, please try again soon!');
>     </script> <?php } ?>
```

Results in this: 
[image]